# Problem with playing audio files on ios which is recored on android

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, audio

I'm using cordova-plugin-media for recording and playing audio files in an ionic project. The problem is when I record a file in android device, in ios device it's not playing but in reverse every sound plays fine. I tried "mp3", "wav" and "aac" format but it doesn't make any difference. can any one help me how to fix it? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the answer. The answer is using "cordova-plugin-media-with-compression" instead of "cordova-plugin-media". Its "startRecordWithCompression" method adds SampleRate to recorded audios which is required in ios.
see the link below:

https://github.com/remoorejr/cordova-plugin-media-with-compression